# PointCloud alignment

Tags: kinect, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting some strange behavior with pointcloud_to_laserscan where after doing some tests it appears that part of the pointcloud isn't being used to update the laser scan.  Although the pointcloud is displayed correctly within Rviz I notice that within pointcloud_to_laserscan I'm getting a significant number of NaNs which are then ignored.  Could this be something to do with 16 byte SSE alignment ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9488/pointcloud-alignment/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-19**:
The point cloud /camera/depth/points appears to be shown correctly within Rviz, with the points which don't make it through pointcloud_to_laserscan being displayed.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-19**:
It's originally coming from /camera/depth/points, then going through cloud_throttle.  It looks as if the throttle isn't doing much, and I can also directly feed in /camera/depth/points and get the same result.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-19**:
What is producing your PointClouds? Do the input clouds contain NaNs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pointcloud_to_laser scan node only takes a slice of the point cloud.  Which is parameterized by min_height and max_height defaulting to 0.1 and 0.15 by default.  [[source]](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/pointcloud_to_laserscan/html/cloud__to__scan_8cpp_source.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1